# Don't center screen when hitting end in vim

Tags: vim

With `nowrap` and when on a long line, hitting the end button takes the cursor to the end of the line (of course). Furthermore, the screen will be centered on the cursor.

It will take the cursor from here:

[image: cursor at right]

to here:

[image: cursor at left]

How can I make it scroll right only up to "line."? And thus have the last "this is a long line." aligned to the right of the window?

Edit: I already know about `sidescroll` and `sidescrolloff` but those only apply when using the arrow keys. It doesn't change behavior for the end key, and thus don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you check `:h ze`

```
ze          Scroll the text horizontally to position the cursor
            at the end (right side) of the screen.  This only
            works when 'wrap' is off.  {not in Vi}
```

so if you create a mapping, map `$` or `<end>` to `$ze` or `<end>ze`, it should work as you wish.

hope it helps.

**EDIT**

if you want to map  like what you wanted in INSERT mode:

```
:set sidescroll=1
:inoremap <End> <Esc><End>zei
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to remap it also in insert mode?